# @tailwindcss/forms plugin not working with React

Tags: reactjs, forms, npm, tailwind-css

I am trying to use the tailwindcss plugin forms, so I've installed it via npm using `npm install @tailwindcss/forms` and added the dependency in the forms section of my tailwindconfig @tailwindcss/forms with `plugins: [ require("@tailwindcss/forms") ]`. According to https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms it must now be active, and it does seem to be installed - at least I don't get an error after starting the server. Hoewever, when styling some checkboxes e.g. with `<input type="checkbox" class="rounded text-pink-500" />` the styles are not applied.

Comment: do you have a create-react-app?

Comment: @MWO yes I do have create-react-app

Comment: and did you install tailwind according to the documentation?https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: @MWO yes and I've checked all the steps, nothing is different. Tailwindcss classes are applied regularly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick was pretty simple for me. it required an individual installation for forms.

`npm install @tailwindcss/forms` - did the trick. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

In `tailwind.config.js` modify plugin to use `class` strategy.

```js
// tailwind.config.js
plugins: [
 require("@tailwindcss/forms")({
   strategy: 'class',
 }),
],
```

and add `form-checkbox` class to input element.

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox rounded text-pink-500" />
```

This method worked for me.